# Tag filter subscription for all English sites

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters, subscription

I'm using a tag filter to get email updates about the [wikipedia](/questions/tagged/wikipedia) tag. Since this tag appears on several sites, I chose the All Sites option.

That worked fine for me, but now I have received an email with a question from Portuguese Stack Overflow. Since I don't speak Portuguese, I'm not interested in questions there. But because of the nature of the tag, it could appear on some of the many SE sites where it currently doesn't exist. Because of that, I don't think selecting just the 7 sites where the tag currently exists is a good solution.

Because of that, I propose to add another option to the tag filter form: All English Sites.

Comment: Or an "unsubscribe filter from site X" or "mute this site" option on the email as they come in from that site

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather see something like an exception list. The page allows you to specify a list of sites already. Why not just modify the system so that the two options are: "All sites except those in the list below" and "Only the sites in the list below"? For those who just want the normal "All sites" option, they can just leave the list empty. For a list like you want, you could add Stack Overflow in Portuguese to your exception list since it's not in English.

I think a language option would be confusing, because there are sites that use *both* English and whatever language they're discussing (pretty much all the *Something Language* sites allow both languages, but have different rules on which language is used for tags). Would you expect those language sites to appear or not appear when that "English Only" option is selected? I have a feeling some would argue that they should appear and others would argue that they shouldn't.

Similarly, the same modification could be applied to the tag filter, allowing the options "All questions except those with the tags below" and "Only questions with the tags below".

Comment: Well, exception list might not work as well when/if new non-English sites start being added more regularly.

Comment: @svick, but think how much more powerful site black/white listing would be than just language. Big picture this could be used for language and so much more!